# How to add a class to the webform error message

Tags: webforms

When people fill in incorrectly in my webform, the error message will output as follow, e.g:

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger">
  <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" href="#">×</a>
<h4 class="element-invisible">Error message</h4>
 <ul>
  <li>Name* field is required.</li>
  <li>Email field is required.</li>
  <li>Contact No. field is required.</li>
  <li>Comment field is required.</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Now, I wonder is there way I can add a CSS class to this message so that I can target this particular message that fired by this particular webform. e.g

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger webform">
 ........
</div>
```

or even more specific, add the ID to the message .e.g

```
<div class="alert alert-block alert-danger" id="message-webform-client-block-212">
  ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is no, since the errors set in the error message box could come from any source, meaning the errors in that `<div>` aren't necessarily just your webform errors. Since it looks like you're using your webform as a block I'm guessing you can't target a body class to check if you're on a particular page type either.

If you were setting your own error messages you could add a `<span>` around the message with your custom class, but that would mean bypassing the validation handling webforms provide.

One possible solution would be to use JavaScript to find `<li>` elements that have text matching the error messages you want to style and moving them to a custom container. Another could be creating a [YOURTHEMENAME_status_messages()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_status_messages/7) function in your theme's template.php and doing a regular expression or string comparison to output specific error messages in a separate container. This route would affect all error message using the same text though, so it could affect an error message that was not from your webform.

Comment: Matching the error messages is a good hint. If I make the label name to be more unique, instead of just "Name", put something like "Enquiry Name", the error output "Enquiry name field is required." will be more specific to target. Thanks.